# (Excel Data Validation) how can I apply data validation to restrict certain ages?

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with DOB data. I am trying to implement data validation so people under age 18, or people 75 or older cannot enter their DOB. I can calculate their age using...

DATEIF(D2, TODAY(), "y"), which is in screenshot below attached...

[image]

But, how can I use this information to restrict the data input with data validation? I can't seem to implement the DATEDIF equation into a data validation rule.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What Excel version are you using? For me `=AND(DATEDIF(D2,TODAY(),"y")>=18,DATEDIF(D2,TODAY(),"y")<75)` works in data validation using Excel 365.

Comment: So Data Validation will reference the contents of a cell, which means if you reference the result of the calculation in the other comment then you have what you need.

Answer (score 0):

So, just to show it working:

[image]
What makes it work is the absolute reference.

If I enter in cell D2 17.1.1940 it then asks to retry.

Note:
I separated the two tests and the test in Data Validation is that both have to be true.

Comment: sweet, this is what i needed, thanks! what i can't figure out is how to get this applied to an entire column. I want to apply it to all of D, so people can't input DOBs outside of this range. Any idea?